# Installing Ubuntu in shrinked unallocated space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have installed UBUNTU in my laptop and now I want to install ubuntu in my PC also but there are four partition in my windows so I can't use install ubuntu alongside option. So my plan is to shrink my c drive and create an unallocated space. My question is can I use something else option now? Can I delete that unallocated space and create new drive to install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You don't delete unallocated space, its space thats empty. The reason you can't create a new partition is because you reach your 4 primary limit or 3 primary 1 extended limit on MBR. It would be easier for use to see your drive format, Open cmd and type "diskmgmt.msc" then post a picture.

I'm going to guess your layout since there usally similar. There could be a 199mb "SYSTEM" partiton, then windows, then recovery, and last tools. You could convert the tools into a logical partiton, then shrink the windows partiton and move it behind the tools. Last you would create a new partition, in which you would install ubuntu in. Ease Partiton is free and makes things alot easier (note: it can't read ext4). As always Backup your data!

Answer (score 1):

The four-primary-partition limit exists for the [Master Boot Record (MBR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partitioning system, but not for the newer [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) system. Most computers sold with Windows 8, and some sold with Windows 7, particularly since mid-2011, use GPT. So do Intel-based Macs. Thus, it's possible that you're concerned over nothing.

If your disk uses MBR, then you'll have to either delete one of your four existing partitions or, as Aaahh suggests, convert one from primary to logical form. Most partitioning tools can't do this conversion, but some can. In the Linux world, AFAIK only my [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) (part of the Ubuntu `gdisk` package) can do the trick, at least directly. There are caveats, though; see the FixParts documentation for details. I've heard that some Windows tools can do it, too, but I don't know details about them. If you do such a conversion, you've got to be careful about which partition you convert. Most importantly, you should not convert the Windows boot (usually `C:` in Windows) partition to logical.